# Discord.py how can I use json to store a users id and only a users id

Tags: json, python-3.x, discord.py

So, how would I store a users discord id in json, and only a users id, nothing else. Not sure how to do this.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: What, like a list of ids, or literally a single id in a file?

Comment: List of ids, but when a user uses a command, it gets the users id. And for every user that uses it the id is added to the file @PatrickHaugh

Comment: A list of strings is already valid json.  What part are you struggling with?  You can use `json.load` to get the list from the file, then modify it with regular python, then use `json.dump` to write it back to the file.  I don't even think you need json for this.  Just keep a text file with newline-separated ids.  Use the "append" file mode to add new ones when you see them.  Then just load that file into a `set` in your `on_ready` event.

Comment: Can you put a answer explaining it with a example? @PatrickHaugh

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a regular txt file for this. Append new ids when you see them.  When you start your bot, load all the ids into a `set` to prevent duplicates

```
ids = set()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    with open("ids.txt") as f:
        for id in f:
            ids.add(id.strip())

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def register(ctx):
    id = ctx.message.author.id
    if id not in ids:
        ids.add(id)
        with open("ids.txt", "a") as f:
            print(id, file=f)
        await bot.say("ID {} added".format(id))
```

Comment: What would I need to put in the .txt file if anything?

Comment: I think it should work with just an empty file.  If you do put some ids in it to start, make sure that they are separated by a single newline, and that the file ends with a newline