# Read UserID and write to Json file with command

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Is it possible to write Author User ID to Json file automatically when author use a command.

Example: i have a json file with data like below.

```
{"names": [
{"UserID": "xxxxx", "Name": "Steve", "Sex": "Male", "age": "30"},
{"UserID": "xxxxx", "Name": "Rachel", "Sex": "Female", "age": "25"},
{"UserID": "xxxxx", "Name": "George", "Sex": "Male", "age": "22"} ] }
```

Here we add a command to edit json file.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def dump(ctx):
    with open('data.json') as json_file:
```

like if a member types `!dump Rachel` bot needs to gets his UserID and automatically added to Json file in `xxxxx` replace this with authors UserID `"UserID": "xxxxx"`

So it reduces time to add User ID manually to all lists.

Comment: You might find this recent question helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51429600/discord-py-how-can-i-use-json-to-store-a-users-id-and-only-a-users-id

Comment: @PatrickHaugh yes i tried it and it dumped author id to txt file.  I need to make it dump to exactly in `{"UserID": "xxxxx", "Name": "Steve", "Sex": "Male", "age": "30"},` replacing `xxxxx`  if he use `!register Steve`

Comment: If the ids are the same length you could try navigating to the start of the old id and overwriting  just those bytes. Otherwise, you'll have to read the whole json file into a python object, modify that object, and write the whole file back.  You could potentially split this across two commands: one that modifies the python object and the other a `!save` command.  That's still not going to scale particularly well, I recommend setting up a database.